# WordPress: Creating new WP Users from CiViCRM Contacts

Tags: wordpress, profile, civicrm-contact, sync

My situation is I have an Individual database of 11,344 Contacts in Drupal Civi, and I want to turn them all into WP Users. I know I can convert Users into Contacts, but I want to do it the other way around.
 I have pointed my WordPress CiViCRM to a drupal Civi database which I need very much. I want the CiViCRM members to show under WordPress users but this isn't working. I have downloaded the plugin  [CiviCRM WordPress Profile Sync](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-profile-sync/); but I can see the plugin on button on my dashboard to even try something. Can you please help me? I really need this issue solved. Thank you

Comment: Do the Contacts you want to make into WordPress Users have CiviCRM Memberships?

Answer (score 1):

How i would do is

1. Export contacts with email address that want to be user.
2. Install Wordpress [export/import user](https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-customers-import-export-for-wp-woocommerce/) plugin.
3. Change the un-supervised dedupe rule to have only email address
4. Import users via Wordpress screen using exported csv from CiviCRM
5. Switch back un-supervised dedupe rule

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your support. I finally used the CiviCRM WordPress Profile Sync;  and it seemed to work 89%. My issue now is that I want to be able to build the old CiviCRM system by importing the data step by step so that I can have control over everything. The reason I want to do that is I was trying to create a new event and want to set the fees but the fee settings refuses to save. If the fee is not saved, registration isn't possible. The system has been there for a couple of years now.

Comment: Since mysql contact table is showing 17000 rows whilst contacts in CiviCRM is showing about 13000 contacts, I'm wondering which one to import.I'm planning on copying the mysql contat table of Drupal  straight to my new Wordpress Civicrm database. Is that a good idea?

Comment: I would use CiviCRM UI to export contacts. The table might have contacts that are in trash try doing query with is_deleted = 0 on contact table

Comment: should I do that in civi or Mysql?

Comment: CIvi UI i will suggest

Comment: Ok. I will try that. which one do you suggest to come first? the contacts? or groups? and also, how do I deal with the groups when I import the contacts? do I have to add them individually to the groups? Or I should rather import the the groups first and get almost an entire list of contacts in the end?

Comment: If you have a sync plugin enabled that synchronises wp role with civi group than it should work automatically after you import users

Comment: I have actually tried the import of the contacts from the CiVi interface. When I get to the step of field mapping, I have realized that some field could not be imported because there are no available match. So, I stopped as I don't want to loose any information

Comment: There is a confusion here. You mentioned in your question that you already have Civi contacts stored in CiviCRM but want to create WP user. So either you doing it in a wrong way or you haven't understood my steps mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have pointed the new WordPress Civi DB to a copy of the old Drupal CiVi. but it seems there are still issues so I would like to rather build from scratch.